# Что делать, если удалил файл, принадлежащий пакету?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Ненароком удалил файл `/usr/bin/env`, и теперь даже команда `vagrant up` выдает ошибку:

> bash: /usr/bin/vagrant: /usr/bin/env: плохой интерпретатор: Нет такого файла или каталога

Как его вернуть?

Comment: Узнать из какого пакета env и переустановить его. Может это coreutils

Answer (score 5, accepted):

узнать, какому пакету принадлежит файл, можно так (приведён и типичный ответ):

```
$ dpkg -S /путь/к/файлу
название-пакета: /путь/к/файлу
```

переустановить пакет можно так:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall название-пакета
```

Comment: Пробовал переустанавливать скачав архив с сайта GNU, не помогло. Ваш метод помог. Спасибо :)